Is the notion of a "self" that persists over time an illusion?
If I define "myself" as "my body," my body is constantly changing. At some time t₁, my body corresponds to a specific arrangement of elementary particles. At a different time t₂, with near absolute certainty, that arrangement of particles will be different. Consequently, the arrangement of particles at t₂ would not be "my body" as it was at t₁, but something else.
Alternatively, if I define "myself" as "my consciousness," we encounter a similar issue under reductive physicalism. Under this view, "my consciousness" at t₁ reduces to my body at t₁. Thus, whatever consciousness exists at t₂ would correspond to the body at t₂, which, with near absolute certainty, is different. Therefore, the consciousness at t₂ would also be different (for more on this, see this answer to What are the sufficient conditions for the identity of consciousness at different locations in space and time?).
If "I" am neither "my body" nor "my consciousness" (both of which cannot be precisely defined as they are in constant flux, at least under reductive physicalism), does it follow that the notion of a "self" that persists over time is an illusion? Is there no ontologically fundamental "self" that persists over time, but rather only an illusion created by elementary particles in continuous motion and change?

Related questions:

Is there any coherent argument in support of consciousness being an illusion? (not a duplicate, since in this question I'm asking about the self as an illusion, not consciousness as an illusion. See also: What's the difference (if any) between "self" and "consciousness"?)
If consciousness is an emergent property of brain state, does this mean that we can only truly exist for 1 Planck unit of time? (I like this question a lot, very closely related, but this question seems to be implicitly assuming that the self is identical to consciousness, where consciousness is viewed as instantaneous snapshots. In contrast, in my question I'm not assuming that the self is identical to consciousness necessarily)


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The Buddha said that 2500 years ago. As best I know, he hasn't been shown to be in error.

Yes, it is an illusion for the reasons you stated already, and is the sole reason why human beings invented the illusion of free will. Without a self, there is no will. And without a will, there is no freedom to talk about.
One may use a Kantian analogy to illustrate this. Kant believed that we not directly observe space: we only observe its contents. Even if one is not a physicalist, one can notice from pure observation that one only observes sensations/thoughts/moods as individual components. The feeling of a “self” is an inference, which is yet another content in consciousness. The content, or part, cannot equal the whole.  It is never directly perceived because there is nothing to perceive.
What would this self consist of? Where would it be? What would represent it? Everything is ever changing in your brain and consciousness.

Take my vote.. Just want to observe how ingrained the notion of self is in our language. When you say that 'one observes sensations or thoughts', you are bound to get the question: who does the observing?

Self - is real, physical mirror. It can be recognized by other "mirrors".
This mirror - reflects the universe, and similar to "other mirrors", these reflections of the universe are an illusion, slightly different in each mirror.
So practically, you can change or destroy the mirror. You can add some refractions that would change your illusion of the universe. What you cannot change (apparently) is the source of illusion.

Sounds like Indra's Net.
